# How to test AdMob before publishing application to Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I followed [this document](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start) to integrate the AdMob to my application.The testing banner is shown correctly. My question is where should I get my own banner_ad_unit_id before I publish the app to Google play?

**P.S.**: I have an AdMob account and my application is published as beta version to Google Play already. But when I was trying to create ad banner in AdMob, it required me to search the application in Google Play.

Comment: without publishing the app to google play , the answer you are looking is not possible as per admob new guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching and linking the app in your AdMob account, you should be able to go to the ad unit management page and copy your ad unit id. It is right under the description for the banner.

[image: AD_UNIT_ID]

Answer (score 2):

Actually when you create ad banner, there is an option called "add your app manually" and you can use that to add your app.